# SwiftSoup assigning data to a custom class

Tags: swift, xcode, parsing

Began to parse using the SwiftSoup library. I use a custom class and an array defined by a class:

```
names: [AddClass] = []
class AddClass: NSObject {

var name500: String 
var date500: String
var ima: String
var prices: String
var sales: String
var display_price: String

init (name500: String, date500: String, ima: String, prices: String, sales: String, display_price: String) {
self.name500 = name500
self.date500 = date500
self.ima = ima
self.prices = prices
self.sales = sales
self.display_price = display_price
}   
}
```

Parsing looks like this:

```
var Title: [Element] = []
var pp: Int = 1
var myURL: URL!

do {
while pp < 6{
    myURL = URL(string: "https://..../\(pp)")
    pp += 1
    let html = try! String(contentsOf: myURL!, encoding: .utf8)
    let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(html)

    Title += try doc.select(".item-details-title")
}


} catch Exception.Error(let type, let message) {
print(message)
} catch {
print("error")
}
```

The question is, how can you assign data to the name500 class variable obtained in Title?

Title in turn has the text that I need:

```
Title.map{$0.text()}
```

Previously assigned data in a different way of parsing and worked like

```
names.map {names in
 primerTitle.map {
 names.name500 += $0.text() 
 }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but loading data synchronously from a remote URL is very very bad habit. It blocks the current thread, And `try` without catching errors will inevitably cause a crash. And please conform to the naming convention and name variables with a starting lowercase letter.

Comment: im use 
    } catch Exception.Error(let type, let message) {
print(message)
} catch {
print("error")
}

Comment: This catches `try doc` but **not** `try! String` And `print("error")` is meaningless. Print the `error` (without double quotes)

Comment: how can I assign the data from the Element to my custom array?